# Value de Input sendo exibido no HTML

Tags: php

Dentro de uma **variavel** **PHP** tenho um conteúdo **HTML**. para ser exibido.

Então eu fiz

```
$htmlPDF = $html;

$html .= "
    <form action='pdf.php' method='post'>
        <input type='hidden' name='htmlPDF' value='" . $htmlPDF . ".</div>' />
        <input type='submit' class='button formularios' value='Gerar PDF' />
    </form><br /><br />
    <button id='btnGrafico' class='button formularios'>Gerar Gráfico</button><br />
    <canvas class='line-chart'></canvas>
";
```

Essa *manobra* é que antes de exibir os botões eu preciso pegar conteúdo **HTML** até então.

O **problema**:

Quando vou exibir **$html**, além de sair o conteudo em si uma vez está saindo também o **conteudo** da **variavel** $**htmlPDF** que esá em

```
<input type='hidden' name='htmlPDF' value='" . $htmlPDF . "' />
```

Em outras palavras, contedo **duplicado**.

O quje está **errado** aqui?

**Obs**.: se eu fizer:

```
<input type='hidden' name='htmlPDF' value='' />
```

O **conteúdo** exibe **normalmente**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já tentoi sem as aspas duplas: deixando apenas `value=' $htmlPDF ' `

Comment: sim, deu a mesma coisa. Adicionei uma imagem!

Comment: O conteúdo é duplicado porque você iguala o `$htmlPDF` ao conteúdo anterior do '$html' aqui: `$htmlPDF = $html;` ... Ou seja, à variável `$htmlPDF` é atribuido TODO o conteudo do `$html` anterior. Depois você concatena TODO o conteúdo com a variável htmlPDF que contém todo o HTML anterior...

Comment: Mas como eu deveria fazer para colocar $htmlPDF como value de INPUT hidden de modo que não ocorra essa duplicação? Essa é a excencia da pergunta e minha dúvida! E também não vejo no código lugar algum omde dou echo ou print na variavel $htmlPDF. Viu onde está minha dificuldade?

Comment: Dreamweaver? @_@

Answer (score 0):

Ja tentou isso?

```
$htmlPDF = $html;

$html .= "
    <form action='pdf.php' method='post'>
        <input style = 'display: none' name='htmlPDF' value='" . $htmlPDF . ".</div>' />
        <input type='submit' class='button formularios' value='Gerar PDF' />
    </form><br /><br />
    <button id='btnGrafico' class='button formularios'>Gerar Gráfico</button><br />
    <canvas class='line-chart'></canvas>
";
```

Acho que o css pode te salvar nessa, eu faço isso aqui..

Comment: Não funcionou amigo. Continua exibindo o conteúdo. Mas o input já era do tipo hidden

Answer (score 0):

**Resolvido**:

```
html .= '
    <form action="pdf.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="htmlPDF" value="' . $htmlPDF . '</div>" />
        <input type="submit" class="button formularios" value="Gerar PDF" >
    </form><br /><br />
    <button id="btnGrafico" class="button formularios">Gerar Gráfico</button><br />
    <canvas class="line-chart"></canvas>
';
```

Bastou **inverter** as **aspas** e deu certo!

Onde estava aspas duplas coloquei simples e vice versa.

Só não entendi porque mas rsolveu e é isso que importa!